# Search object literal and return first key/value pair that matches regex

Tags: javascript, regex

This does what I want:

```
function test(data){
    for(var key in data){
        if(/_is$/.test(key)){
          var obj = {}
          obj[key] = data[key];
          return obj;
        }
    }
}

test( {a: 'a', user_id_is: '1', b: 'b'} )
> Object {user_id_is: "1"}
```

But 8 lines of code for such a simple task looks inefficient. Is there a more concise way to achieve such a basic task in JavaScript, something like how Ruby does it?

> ```
> data.detect {|item| item =~ /_is$/}
> ```

Comment: Very nice question, welcome to Code Review!

Comment: What do you mean by "the _first_ key/value pair"? I don't believe that object attributes are in any particular order. Do you mean "_any_ matching key"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To be fair, the entire thing in Ruby would be a few more method calls:

```
{:a => 1, :b => 2}.detect { |i| i != :b }.each_slice(2).to_h
```

Can we do this in a similar number of lines in JavaScript?

First, we can shorten the 8 line original down to 5 lines if we use ES2015 syntax:

```
function test(data) {
  for(let key of data) {
    if(/_is$/.test(key)) return {[key]: data[key]};
  }
}
```

Adding in ES2015 methods we can use `reduce` and an arrow function to get rid of the `return` at the cost of making this always loop over all the keys in the object (now down to 3 lines):

```
const test = data => Object.keys(data).reduce((obj, key) =>
  obj || /_is$/.test(key) ? {[key]: data[key]} : undefined, undefined
);
```

If we're willing to use ES2017, we can use `Object.entries` and a helper function to get the line count down to 2 at the expense of a little legibility:

```
const toObj = ([key, value] = []) => key ? {[key]: value} : undefined;
const test = data => toObj(Object.entries(data).find(([key, value]) => /_is$/.test(key)));
```

Comment: Very nice answer, welcome to Code Review!

Comment: Note: for..in and for..of do different things, so it depends on what OP is using for `data`.